# Bootstrap 4 - Centrar divs horizontalmente

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

tengo este código:

```
<div id="contacto" class="text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1>¡Contáctanos!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="text-left">
        <img src="/images/icon-phone.png" alt="" style="max-height: 80px; max-width: 100%; float: left;">
        <h4>Teléfono / WhatsApp:<br>+54 3476 324762 / (+540347615597235)</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="text-left">
        <img src="/images/icon-mail.png" alt="" style="max-height: 80px; max-width: 100%; float: left;">
        <h4>Correo Electrónico:<br>cervuslabs@gmail.com</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y no puedo lograr centrar horizontalmente los divs que contienen las imagenes y texto de teléfono y correo electrónico. ¿Alguna ayuda? Estuve googleando un rato y no encontré como lograrlo centrar de la forma que quiero.

Answer (score 0):

Hola añade la clase *text-center* a las etiquetas que contienen el texto que quieres centrar, en tu caso quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
<div id="contacto" class="text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1>¡Contáctanos!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="text-left">
        <img src="/images/icon-phone.png" alt="" style="max-height: 80px; max-width: 100%; float: left;">
        <h4 class="text-center">Teléfono / WhatsApp:<br>+54 3476 324762 / (+540347615597235)</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="text-left">
        <img src="/images/icon-mail.png" alt="" style="max-height: 80px; max-width: 100%; float: left;">
        <h4 class="text-center">Correo Electrónico:<br>cervuslabs@gmail.com</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos